# Problem with read csv file in R from excel

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a problem with loading csv files from excel in R.
I am saving data (looks like this for example:

| Patient | Protein 1 | Protein 2 | Protein 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 1.2 | 4.5 | 0 |
| P2 | 4.0 | 6.2 | 0 |
| P3 | 5.2 | 84.2 | 0.1 |
| P4 | 30.1 | 79.2 | 52.3 |
| P5 | 4.0 | 10.1 | 0.1 |
| P6 | 0.8 | 3.6 | 0 |
| P7 | 1.6 | 8.3 | 23.7 |
| P8 | 5.5 | 10.0 | 0 |

) as a CSV file (*.csv) - file1.csv in the folder "data" on the desktop
I then type the commands in R studio:

```r
File = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Data\\file1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
File
```

Instead of getting a file with column divisions I get data under the form:
8 obs. of 1 variable
[image]

On the console it looks like this:
[image]
Significantly, previously as I saved the data in .csv format and I also load it now in R studio, it works without any problem. So most likely the problem is in saving from excel. I don't recall changing any settings in it. I don't know what could be the cause. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

I save the data the same way ( or at least I think it does) and load it as before. I don't know what happened, but it bothers me when running proteomic analyses.
I would like it to load into R studio a file that generates 8 obs. of 4 variable. I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `read.csv2()` instead, as `read.csv()` assumes comma as a separator.

Comment: It looks like your field separator is `;`, not `,`.

Comment: The field separator used by Excel CSV export is controlled by decimal(!) separator of your system locale and/or Excel settings.